# AnonymousDelegate help for c#

Tags: c#, anonymous-delegates

I need help with this

```
ParallelOptions parallelOption = new ParallelOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1000
};
Parallel.ForEach<string>(strs, parallelOption, (string a0, ParallelLoopState a1, long a2)
     => new VB$AnonymousDelegate_0<string, ParallelLoopState, long, object>((string url, ParallelLoopState i, long j) 
     => {
```

`VB$AnonymousDelegate_0<` is giving me an error

Comment: Are you trying to convert a VB script to c#?  Where are you getting $AnonymousDelegate_0?

Comment: What's the error and what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a lambda in a place where the compiler should be able to infer types.

So, you should be able to do

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    strs, 
    parallelOption
    (s, state, i) => {
        // lambda body
    });
```

without any other work. The type of `s` will be inferred from the type of `strs`, and the other two types will be inferred by overload resolution finding the `Parallel.ForEach` call.

[Related link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21169964/what-is-the-equivalent-c-sharp-code-for-a-vb-net-anonymous-delegate)